# How to send image API From laravel to slim

Tags: laravel, slim, guzzle

I have an API created by SLIM to save an image client side.

this is my controller code

```
  $response = Http::withOptions([
        'verify' => false,
    ])->post('http://localhost/events_platforma/create/event
    ', [
        "title" => $request->title,
        "alias" => $request->alias,
        "description" => $request->description,
        "image" => $request->file('image'),
        "status" => $request->status,
    ]);
```

And it through back error when i return   that response
[image]

When i use with Postman it work fine and saves a file but when it from Laravel app it give that error

Answer (score 1):

Everything is given in the docs.
 use `attach()`

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
        'verify' => false,
    ])->attach(
        'image', $request->file('image'), "image" . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    )->post('http://localhost/events_platforma/create/event', [
        "title" => $request->title,
        "alias" => $request->alias,
        "description" => $request->description,
        "status" => $request->status,
    ]);
```

#### 2nd Approach

```
$response = Http::withOptions([
        'verify' => false,
        'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'image',
            'contents' => $request->file('image')
        ]]
    ])->post('http://localhost/events_platforma/create/event
    ', [
        "title" => $request->title,
        "alias" => $request->alias,
        "description" => $request->description,
        "status" => $request->status,
    ]);
```

Comment: It work but now it  says A 'contents' key is required

Comment: what is your guzzle version?

Comment: My guzzle version is 7.2

Comment: this issue was raised in may 2020, and it was resolved, I don't know why you are getting this issue. I have provided a second solution you can try that